# Hide the Password tips

Tags: users

How can I hide those password tips???  You know,when the enduser tries toregister and as soon as he clicks on the password field the following messages appear:

> ```
> To make your password stronger: 
> •Make it at least 6 characters 
> •Add lowercase letters
> •Add uppercase letters 
> •Add numbers 
> •Add punctuation
> ```

Simple CSS "display:none" won't do the trick here.

I still want to keep the password strength meter.Just need to get rid of the Password tips messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it via CSS, just add the `!important`:

```
.password-suggestions {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Another option is to copy the `modules/user/user.js` file to your theme, add it to `.info` file and edit it the way you want.

Comment: Yep. The "!important" bit did the trick. Thanks!